# Alternative to script command getting directory names (using ls & awk)

Tags: shell-script

Related to my question about awk being ignored by cron, are there any alternatives to awk? This is the line in question:

```
for dirlist in `ls -l $WEBFOLDER | awk '$1 ~ /d/ {print $10 }' `
```

I don't know awk so I don't understand the `$1 ~ /d/` part, but I think what it does is that it prints the 10th column out of the `ls -l` result. As I can't use awk as of current, is there an alternative to getting the directory names without using awk?

EDIT: The line above only outputs the names. No lines or dots, just the names.

Comment: If you simply want the directory output, `ls` already has that built-in functionality with the `-d` parameter.  `ls -lhad "$WEBFOLDER"/*` will list all directories inside `$WEBFOLDER`, including hidden directories, symlinks, etc. (`-a`), in human-readable (`-h`) format.

Comment: @rubynorails how do I redirect the output? For example, in the code above, I tried replacing `-l` with `-d` and removing the awk part, but it does't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple for loop:

```
for dir in "$WEBFOLDER"/*/; do
  basename "$dir"
done
```

If you also want directories starting with a dot:

```
for dir in "$WEBFOLDER"/.*/ "$WEBFOLDER"/*/; do
  basename "$dir"
done
```

Comment: I've tried using this before, but it outputs the whole directory. I only need the names.

Comment: @IBG see my edit

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Just a question: what is the `.` in `.*` for? I used absolute path to replace $WEBFOLDER to test it, but it shows nothing. I removed the `.` and it worked just fine. Sorry if it sounds dumb, I'm not yet familiar with shell scripting.

Comment: @IBG Sorry, was my fault. The dot in the first example is not nessecary. I removed it. The dot is for directories starting with a dot. The * alone will not match them.

Answer (score 3):

How about using find?
You can easily get directories like this:

```
find . -type d
```

You can also limit the depth if needed:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1
```